# How to receive data from Ember send

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, ember.js

How do I send data from Ember to an Express server?

According to the official docs, we can do a save action in a router like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    var photo = this.get('store').createRecord('photo', {
      title: 'ni hao xin ji lu',
      owner: 'ViII',
      city: 'Dalian',
      image: 'fafa.jpg',
      star: 3,
      description: '.....'
    });

    photo.save();
```

On the server side, for example using Express, like this:

```
router.post('/photos', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)//How To Do Here
});
```

Indeed, the server will trigger the post event, but when I search the `req` console out, there is nothing about the photo data from the Ember request.

Did I forgot something? How do I pass data to the server with Ember such that the server can receive it?

I'm using the latest Ember version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Ember will send the data to the server as JSON. You need to tell Express to parse that. I believe Ember's `JSONAPIAdapter` sends a `content-type` header of `application/vnd.api+json`, which needs a bit of extra configuration for the `bodyParser`:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));
```

Comment: yes,need add application/vnd.api+json content type,or change RESTAdapter,just tried,thanks very much.